# Discrete change of an integral result

Tags: integration, physics, quantum-mechanics, change-of-variable

So I was working on ΔS (it is called action in physics but the question I am about to present is purely mathematical).

$S=∫L dt => ΔS=Δ(∫(\frac{1}{2}mv^2 -V)dt)= Δ(∫\frac{1}{2}mv^2 dt)$

The problem I face here is if we were to assume that t interval is small. Then could we say

$$ΔS= Δ(∫\frac{1}{2}mv^2 dt)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt$$

Is this acceptable?

Note: I am reminded that this question may not be seen as "purely mathematical" and decided to wrote this note to avoid confusion regarding terms related to physics. However, this note will get a bit more mathematical towards the end. I asked this question here because I think my problem is more mathematical than physical. m is mass and v is velocity. It is assumed that they are constants. ΔS is "change in action" and is defined as ∫L dt with L being $L=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 -V$. This "change" actually represents deviation from the action of the classical path a particle may follow.

V (potential term) in my first definition of ΔS is not important. What I am trying to show here is that ΔS can be represented as $\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt$. Let's visualise the issue that I am having.

When $Δt<<1$, it is immediate to see that $∫\frac{1}{2}mv^2 dt=\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt$

So we have $Δ(\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δ(Δt)$. This is a serious issue for me. I felt like we can overcome this by saying $Δt=t'$ and thus we have $$Δ(\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δ(Δt)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt'=ΔS$$

But I need $Δt'\equiv Δt$ and that feels wrong in a mathematical way. It works while making commentaries on a solution but I want to be able to show it mathematically.

If $Δt'\equiv Δt$ somehow works than ΔS becomes $$ΔS=\frac{1}{2}mv^2Δt=\frac{1}{2}m(\frac{Δx}{Δt})^2Δt=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{(Δx)^2}{Δt}=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{\eta^2}{\epsilon}$$
Don't worry about $\eta$ and $\epsilon$. They are just a symbol. They still show changes in the respective "variables". That's not changed.

Comment: Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial :)

Comment: This isn't "purely mathematical", unfortunately - for starters, most of your terms are left undefined (without physics there's no context to make it clear what they mean), and you're conflating values and functions.

It seems likely what you're missing is some conditions on the behavior of $m$ and $v$, but you really do need to define your terms to get an answer here.

Comment: @user3716267 I added a note. Was it clarifying... or just made things worse?

Comment: Didn't really change much in either direction; physical notions like "mass" and "time" do not feature directly in mathematics.  Inasmuch as there's a mathematics question latent in this, it looks like one about the behavior of certain functions of a (real?) variable.

If you're looking for a mathematical justification for/analysis of a lot of the common physics "tricks" you're doing here, you should seek out a text on "nonstandard calculus" or "nonstandard analysis."  I think your confusion here is largely notational; a lot of what you've written fails to "type-check" in math context.

Comment: To be more concrete: you need to state what class of *mathematical* object your various symbols represent (e.g. "real variable" or "function of a real variable"), you need to give bounds to your integrals, and you need to formally define your $\Delta$ operator.

Comment: Your "discrete change" does not make your problem part of discrete mathematics

Comment: @caduk thanks. I will keep this in mind in the future : )

Comment: my initial intention for adding that tag was for a possible case where an insight from that area of math would be enlightening for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  First of all, the Lagrangian is $L = mv^2/2 - V$, and not the energy as you define.  Second, I don't understand why you got rid of the potential term.  Is this a variation of some sort?  If the potential is a constant, then there would be no force and it's a free particle.  Is this the case that you're trying to analyze?

Comment: I am aware @B215826 but it seems I have made a HUGE typo and wrote “+” instead of “-“. Thanks for notifying me. Typo should be fixed now.

Comment: The potential in the equation does not depend on time and is dependent on $\frac{x+x’}{2}$. x and x’ is initial and final for x-coordinate. So when I check ΔS, it disappears.